# Can't read image from internal storage using react-native android

Tags: android, image, react-native, local-storage

I can't read image file when i pass "file://" in uri

```
<View>
  <Text>
    YOLO
  </Text>
  <Image
    style={styles.tinyLogo}
    source={{
      uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Fun.jpg",
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Are you saving the image then trying to display it? I've been using react-native-fs which has variables like DocumentDirectoryPath which handles cross platform paths for you. There was a time when I could have told you the proper android path format but even then it was a hassle, react-native-fs makes it simple

Comment: Yes, the image exists in file path, i tried using rn fetch blob no luck and I couldn't try with react-native-fs, for some reason I can't seem to be able to install it :/

Comment: @RaiyanKhalilShuvo i faced simlar issue with path, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821291/fetch-request-fails-on-expo-on-react-native-on-android/65502507#65502507), might help you

Comment: yes rn fetch blob has something similar, https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs

Comment: You only have this problem on an Android 10 device?

Comment: Yes with android 10, i was also trying to play video using the same thing but that doesn't seem to work either. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274179/how-can-i-access-my-videos-from-internal-storage-with-react-native-video

Comment: Needed to downgrade to android 7.1.1 for it to work, still not sure why it didn't work on Android 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try by adding the below tag inside the **application** tag in the **AndroidManifest** file:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

For Example:

```
<application
    // ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
>
//...
</application>
```

Also, make sure that you are asking the users for **storage permissions**.

Comment: Your info that requesting legacy only helps for an Android 10 device is missing.

Comment: This works, but I had to change the compileSdkVersion to 29 from 28 for it to work on the new android version. Thank you

Comment: @RaiyanKhalilShuvo Glad to hear, and YES, It requires you to make the API version to 29 as it is the change for the Android 10 Version and From now onwards you must require to set the API version to 29 to upload the app to the play store.